# Rails does not include styles using require_tree and scss

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

There is the following code application.css.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
.table tbody > tr > td.vertical-align {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This file is in 'stylesheets' directory. There is also 'home.css.scss' file in the same dir. But if I move this style from 'application' file to 'home' file browser doesn't see this style. What's the trouble? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: just uncomment the `require_tree .` in application.css.scss

Comment: @CbaBhusal where do you see `require_tree` to be commented?

Comment: in the code you posted, there is require_tree commented see

Comment: @CbaBhusal it's not a commented! This is the way assets manifest are written in rails. Read the docs first http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html. It has `*= require_tree .` after the `*= require_self`.

Comment: I understand I you didn't comment that however you can rewrite those.

Comment: Rewrite what? Nonsense...

Answer (score 2):

in my case I have imported bootstrap at the end of the file followed by styles, this must be the problem

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";

.table tbody > tr > td.vertical-align {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

also I'd say you should try to put `require tree` after `require self`:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
```

this makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

From the Rails Asset Pipeline docs:

> If you want to use multiple Sass files, you should generally use the Sass @import rule instead of these Sprockets directives. When using Sprockets directives, Sass files exist within their own scope, making variables or mixins only available within the document they were defined in.
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

So in your case you can move the styles you declared in `application.css.scss` into a separate file (say: `table_styles.css.scss`) and then rewrite your manifest file as:

```
@import "bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "table_styles";
// Import any other files that would have been imported by require_tree
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can use sass variables and mixins and you have better control over the load order of your stylesheets.